# Default Button for ImageButton in Panel not working in IE-7 & IE-8

Tags: asp.net

I have a search page which has selection criteria & two image buttons Search & Clear. I want to fire Search Click whenever user enters in any of the selection criteria. I put the search criteria & button in Panel & set the default button to Search. It works fine in Firefox & Chrome but doesn't work in IE7 or IE8. My preference is not to attach keydown event to all the search criteria textbox & dropdown. Any idea what's different in IE 7-8 which is stopping this to work.

ASP.NET version is 3.5

Here is my html hierarchy

Search Criterias & buttons are here

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Button` control instead of `ImageButton` as stated by this [**article**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/921277).

Comment: Just tried that as well :(. That also works in firefox but not in IE

Comment: clear the IE cache and re-try. if it still not works, share your code.

Comment: Tried to clear the cache but it didn't work. I have uploaded the usercontrol html code here : https://rapidshare.com/files/452317172/UserControl1.ascx

Comment: There was a javascript which was stopping enter to fire. And it works even with image button